# Google cloud run giving 404 for my docker app in port 8000

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I~m trying to deploy my app into Gooogle cloud run but it's showing me this image [image]

In my localhost the app works fine and these are my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server --requirepass devpassword
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  website:
    build: .
    command: >
      gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" --reload "snakeeyes.app:create_app()"
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/snakeeyes'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery worker -l info -A snakeeyes.blueprints.contact.tasks
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/snakeeyes'

volumes:
  redis:
```

And this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y \
    build-essential libpq-dev --no-install-recommends

ENV INSTALL_PATH /snakeeyes
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN pip install --editable .

# CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile - "snakeeyes.app:create_app()"
CMD gunicorn -c "python:config.gunicorn" "snakeeyes.app:create_app()"
```

How can I fix this?
I setup my container for port 8000 and to accept public requests

EDIT

When I run

```
curl -v https://xxx-q42lz4rc5a-uc.a.run.app/
```

I get

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Edit log

```
{
httpRequest: {
latency: "0.003104020s"
protocol: "HTTP/1.1"
remoteIp: "189.102.84.133"
requestMethod: "GET"
requestSize: "395"
requestUrl: "https://growthgeeks-q42lz4rc5a-uc.a.run.app/"
responseSize: "870"
serverIp: "216.239.32.53"
status: 404
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.22621.963"
}
insertId: "647383350005b235faf2d636"
labels: {
instanceId: "004d9db0be8fbe61fa21785209ea77b301b910f3d3a85b98070364c3b7f349c0afa3801798354327d2c09ecf8a343e703ad66f1343b77e2e753b9b65110486dc4a"
}
logName: "projects/roas-164016/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-05-28T16:37:09.377173714Z"
resource: {
labels: {
project_id: "roas-164016"
revision_name: "growthgeeks-00007-sqg"
location: "us-central1"
configuration_name: "growthgeeks"
service_name: "growthgeeks"
}
type: "cloud_run_revision"
}
severity: "WARNING"
spanId: "8423610564014712292"
timestamp: "2023-05-28T16:37:09.368517Z"
trace: "projects/roas-164016/traces/8a57dc8aba186cf525e63daa0fc2b6a1"
traceSampled: true
}
```

Comment: Review your design to fit Cloud Run contract  and limits. Typically Celery is not suitable in Cloud Run (Use cloud Task or PubSub instead). You can also load sidecar container (it's pretty new!!) https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#sidecars

Comment: The first step is to show details on how you are accessing the URL. There are two areas that can return 404. 1) Google Front End (GFE) due to a hostname mismatch and 2) your backend code. Use the CLI curl and access your URL enabling debug (-v). Edit your post to show the command and HTTP response headers. Next, add the relevant log entries from Cloud Logging.

Comment: Can you add what do you see in logs (Logs Explorer) after making the request? Also I am not sure this is the correct way how to run the app in gunicorn -> `"snakeeyes.app:create_app()"`. I think this should be just the function name, not the actual call (ie. `"snakeeyes.app:create_app"`). Does the app work locally this way?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko added log files
Yes, the way it is it's running locally

Comment: Did you try: `EXPOSE 8080` in Dockefile ?

Comment: It appears that your snakeyes app is returning the 404. You do not show your application source code in your post. Note: for the curl command, I asked for the HTTP headers. You did not include that information. That would confirm which service is returning the HTTP response. Make sure you understand why I am asking for certain details. If you don't understand, research it. That will help you debug problems.

Comment: How I do what you are asking? @JohnHanley

Comment: @razimbres just tried and didn't work

Comment: How to do what?